What is the purpose of referenced_type_descriptions in type definition json?
I noticed that my [manual] ros2 installation contains both builtin_interfaces/msg/Time.json and std_msgs/msg/Header.json and at the same time Header contains an exact copy of Time inside referenced_type_descriptions.
Now, I'm working with a limited ros2 install bundled as a feature of third party sdk. For some reason Time.json is not available and I suspect custom messages using Header work because it contains its own Time.
This would answer my own question, but ...
If I run rosidl_generator_c on a bunch of messages and services (I'm not the one running it, it's inside a .make file created by cmake), everything is fine.
If I mix in one action (that has nothing to do with Header or Time), suddenly missing Time.json becomes an issue (rosidl-cli@4.6.2 reports FileNotFoundError) and once I create the file (either copy from ros2 or extract from Header), everything is fine again.

Welcome to Robotics, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer practical, answerable questions, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it clearer.
Especially what sdk are you using?
